# Can't find file in directory using python pykitti package

Tags: python, linux, directory

I am working with the pykitti package for visualizing the KITTI data set in python. It's having trouble locating the calibration files needed. It looks in a specified directory for these calibration files. I specified the directory in which it should look for these files. However, it still gives me an error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/spb5151/Downloads/KITTI_Data/2011_09_26/calib_imu_to_velo.txt'

It says that it's getting stuck on the open(filepath, 'r') line in my code.However, I have confirmed that this file is located in this directory. I'm using Pycharm as my IDE on linux. I'm new to python and linux so is there anything as far as syntax that I might be missing?

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/spb5151/Documents/pykitti-master')

import pykitti

basedir = '/home/spb5151/Downloads/KITTI_Data'
date = '2011_09_26'
drive = '0019'

# The 'frames' argument is optional - default: None, which loads the whole dataset.
# Calibration and timestamp data are read automatically.
# Other sensor data (cameras, IMU, Velodyne) are available via properties
# that create generators when accessed.
data = pykitti.raw(basedir, date, drive, frames=range(0, 50, 5))

# dataset.calib:      Calibration data are accessible as a named tuple
# dataset.timestamps: Timestamps are parsed into a list of datetime objects
# dataset.oxts:       Returns a generator that loads OXTS packets as named tuples
# dataset.camN:       Returns a generator that loads individual images from camera N
# dataset.gray:       Returns a generator that loads monochrome stereo pairs (cam0, cam1)
# dataset.rgb:        Returns a generator that loads RGB stereo pairs (cam2, cam3)
# dataset.velo:       Returns a generator that loads velodyne scans as [x,y,z,reflectance]

point_velo = np.array([0,0,0,1])
point_cam0 = data.calib.T_cam0_velo.dot(point_velo)

point_imu = np.array([0,0,0,1])
point_w = [o.T_w_imu.dot(point_imu) for o in data.oxts]

for cam0_image in data.cam0:
    pass

rgb_iterator = data.rgb # Assign the generator so it doesn't
cam2_image, cam3_image = next(rgb_iterator)
```

And here is the raw.py file which is included in the pykitti package

```
"""Provides 'raw', which loads and parses raw KITTI data."""

import datetime as dt
import glob
import os
from collections import namedtuple

import numpy as np

import pykitti.utils as utils

__author__ = "Lee Clement"
__email__ = "lee.clement@robotics.utias.utoronto.ca"


class raw:
    """Load and parse raw data into a usable format."""

    def __init__(self, base_path, date, drive, **kwargs):
        """Set the path and pre-load calibration data and timestamps."""
        self.drive = date + '_drive_' + drive + '_sync'
        self.calib_path = os.path.join(base_path, date)
        self.data_path = os.path.join(base_path, date, self.drive)
        self.frames = kwargs.get('frames', None)

        # Setting imformat='cv2' will convert the images to uint8 and BGR for
        # easy use with OpenCV.
        self.imformat = kwargs.get('imformat', None)

        # Pre-load data that isn't returned as a generator
        self._load_calib()
        self._load_timestamps()

    def __len__(self):
        """Return the number of frames loaded."""
        return len(self.timestamps)

    @property
    def oxts(self):
        """Generator to read OXTS data from file."""
        # Find all the data files
        oxts_path = os.path.join(self.data_path, 'oxts', 'data', '*.txt')
        oxts_files = sorted(glob.glob(oxts_path))

        # Subselect the chosen range of frames, if any
        if self.frames is not None:
            oxts_files = [oxts_files[i] for i in self.frames]

        # Return a generator yielding OXTS packets and poses
        return utils.get_oxts_packets_and_poses(oxts_files)

    @property
    def cam0(self):
        """Generator to read image files for cam0 (monochrome left)."""
        impath = os.path.join(self.data_path, 'image_00', 'data', '*.png')
        imfiles = sorted(glob.glob(impath))
        # Subselect the chosen range of frames, if any
        if self.frames is not None:
            imfiles = [imfiles[i] for i in self.frames]

        # Return a generator yielding the images
        return utils.get_images(imfiles, self.imformat)

    @property
    def cam1(self):
        """Generator to read image files for cam1 (monochrome right)."""
        impath = os.path.join(self.data_path, 'image_01', 'data', '*.png')
        imfiles = sorted(glob.glob(impath))
        # Subselect the chosen range of frames, if any
        if self.frames is not None:
            imfiles = [imfiles[i] for i in self.frames]

        # Return a generator yielding the images
        return utils.get_images(imfiles, self.imformat)

    @property
    def cam2(self):
        """Generator to read image files for cam2 (RGB left)."""
        impath = os.path.join(self.data_path, 'image_02', 'data', '*.png')
        imfiles = sorted(glob.glob(impath))
        # Subselect the chosen range of frames, if any
        if self.frames is not None:
            imfiles = [imfiles[i] for i in self.frames]

        # Return a generator yielding the images
        return utils.get_images(imfiles, self.imformat)

    @property
    def cam3(self):
        """Generator to read image files for cam0 (RGB right)."""
        impath = os.path.join(self.data_path, 'image_03', 'data', '*.png')
        imfiles = sorted(glob.glob(impath))
        # Subselect the chosen range of frames, if any
        if self.frames is not None:
            imfiles = [imfiles[i] for i in self.frames]

        # Return a generator yielding the images
        return utils.get_images(imfiles, self.imformat)

    @property
    def gray(self):
        """Generator to read monochrome stereo pairs from file.
        """
        return zip(self.cam0, self.cam1)

    @property
    def rgb(self):
        """Generator to read RGB stereo pairs from file.
        """
        return zip(self.cam2, self.cam3)

    @property
    def velo(self):
        """Generator to read velodyne [x,y,z,reflectance] scan data from binary files."""
        # Find all the Velodyne files
        velo_path = os.path.join(
            self.data_path, 'velodyne_points', 'data', '*.bin')
        velo_files = sorted(glob.glob(velo_path))

        # Subselect the chosen range of frames, if any
        if self.frames is not None:
            velo_files = [velo_files[i] for i in self.frames]

        # Return a generator yielding Velodyne scans.
        # Each scan is a Nx4 array of [x,y,z,reflectance]
        return utils.get_velo_scans(velo_files)

    def _load_calib_rigid(self, filename):
        """Read a rigid transform calibration file as a numpy.array."""
        filepath = os.path.join(self.calib_path, filename)
        data = utils.read_calib_file(filepath)
        return utils.transform_from_rot_trans(data['R'], data['T'])


    def _load_calib_cam_to_cam(self, velo_to_cam_file, cam_to_cam_file):
        # We'll return the camera calibration as a dictionary
        data = {}

        # Load the rigid transformation from velodyne coordinates
        # to unrectified cam0 coordinates
        T_cam0unrect_velo = self._load_calib_rigid(velo_to_cam_file)

        # Load and parse the cam-to-cam calibration data
        cam_to_cam_filepath = os.path.join(self.calib_path, cam_to_cam_file)
        filedata = utils.read_calib_file(cam_to_cam_filepath)

        # Create 3x4 projection matrices
        P_rect_00 = np.reshape(filedata['P_rect_00'], (3, 4))
        P_rect_10 = np.reshape(filedata['P_rect_01'], (3, 4))
        P_rect_20 = np.reshape(filedata['P_rect_02'], (3, 4))
        P_rect_30 = np.reshape(filedata['P_rect_03'], (3, 4))

        data['P_rect_00'] = P_rect_00
        data['P_rect_10'] = P_rect_10
        data['P_rect_20'] = P_rect_20
        data['P_rect_30'] = P_rect_30


        # Create 4x4 matrices from the rectifying rotation matrices
        R_rect_00 = np.eye(4)
        R_rect_00[0:3, 0:3] = np.reshape(filedata['R_rect_00'], (3, 3))
        R_rect_10 = np.eye(4)
        R_rect_10[0:3, 0:3] = np.reshape(filedata['R_rect_01'], (3, 3))
        R_rect_20 = np.eye(4)
        R_rect_20[0:3, 0:3] = np.reshape(filedata['R_rect_02'], (3, 3))
        R_rect_30 = np.eye(4)
        R_rect_30[0:3, 0:3] = np.reshape(filedata['R_rect_03'], (3, 3))

        data['R_rect_00'] = R_rect_00
        data['R_rect_10'] = R_rect_10
        data['R_rect_20'] = R_rect_20
        data['R_rect_30'] = R_rect_30

        # Compute the rectified extrinsics from cam0 to camN
        T0 = np.eye(4)
        T0[0, 3] = P_rect_00[0, 3] / P_rect_00[0, 0]
        T1 = np.eye(4)
        T1[0, 3] = P_rect_10[0, 3] / P_rect_10[0, 0]
        T2 = np.eye(4)
        T2[0, 3] = P_rect_20[0, 3] / P_rect_20[0, 0]
        T3 = np.eye(4)
        T3[0, 3] = P_rect_30[0, 3] / P_rect_30[0, 0]

        # Compute the velodyne to rectified camera coordinate transforms
        data['T_cam0_velo'] = T0.dot(R_rect_00.dot(T_cam0unrect_velo))
        data['T_cam1_velo'] = T1.dot(R_rect_00.dot(T_cam0unrect_velo))
        data['T_cam2_velo'] = T2.dot(R_rect_00.dot(T_cam0unrect_velo))
        data['T_cam3_velo'] = T3.dot(R_rect_00.dot(T_cam0unrect_velo))

        # Compute the camera intrinsics
        data['K_cam0'] = P_rect_00[0:3, 0:3]
        data['K_cam1'] = P_rect_10[0:3, 0:3]
        data['K_cam2'] = P_rect_20[0:3, 0:3]
        data['K_cam3'] = P_rect_30[0:3, 0:3]

        # Compute the stereo baselines in meters by projecting the origin of
        # each camera frame into the velodyne frame and computing the distances
        # between them
        p_cam = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1])
        p_velo0 = np.linalg.inv(data['T_cam0_velo']).dot(p_cam)
        p_velo1 = np.linalg.inv(data['T_cam1_velo']).dot(p_cam)
        p_velo2 = np.linalg.inv(data['T_cam2_velo']).dot(p_cam)
        p_velo3 = np.linalg.inv(data['T_cam3_velo']).dot(p_cam)

        data['b_gray'] = np.linalg.norm(p_velo1 - p_velo0)  # gray baseline
        data['b_rgb'] = np.linalg.norm(p_velo3 - p_velo2)   # rgb baseline

        return data

    def _load_calib(self):
        """Load and compute intrinsic and extrinsic calibration parameters."""
        # We'll build the calibration parameters as a dictionary, then
        # convert it to a namedtuple to prevent it from being modified later
        data = {}

        # Load the rigid transformation from velodyne to IMU
        data['T_velo_imu'] = self._load_calib_rigid('calib_imu_to_velo.txt')

        # Load the camera intrinsics and extrinsics
        data.update(self._load_calib_cam_to_cam(
            'calib_velo_to_cam.txt', 'calib_cam_to_cam.txt'))

        # Pre-compute the IMU to rectified camera coordinate transforms
        data['T_cam0_imu'] = data['T_cam0_velo'].dot(data['T_velo_imu'])
        data['T_cam1_imu'] = data['T_cam1_velo'].dot(data['T_velo_imu'])
        data['T_cam2_imu'] = data['T_cam2_velo'].dot(data['T_velo_imu'])
        data['T_cam3_imu'] = data['T_cam3_velo'].dot(data['T_velo_imu'])

        self.calib = namedtuple('CalibData', data.keys())(*data.values())

    def _load_timestamps(self):
        """Load timestamps from file."""
        timestamp_file = os.path.join(
            self.data_path, 'oxts', 'timestamps.txt')

        # Read and parse the timestamps
        self.timestamps = []
        with open(timestamp_file, 'r') as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                # NB: datetime only supports microseconds, but KITTI timestamps
                # give nanoseconds, so need to truncate last 4 characters to
                # get rid of \n (counts as 1) and extra 3 digits
                t = dt.datetime.strptime(line[:-4], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
                self.timestamps.append(t)

        # Subselect the chosen range of frames, if any
        if self.frames is not None:
            self.timestamps = [self.timestamps[i] for i in self.frames]
```

Comment: Can you paste the code snippet here?

Comment: I just edited the original post to add the code.

Answer (score 0):

Aha, for some reason they seemed to have hardcoded this part so that it doesn't consider your data path. Here's the culprit:

```
data['T_velo_imu'] = self._load_calib_rigid('calib_imu_to_velo.txt')
```

Search for this line in your raw.py file and replace the file with data_path + file to make sure it goes to the right path.

Comment: You might also want to flag this in their github/support page

Comment: I just went to the line of code and tried your fix but it's still saying there is no such file. I tried hard coding the path and that did not work either. It's still saying there is no file with that name.